# 'e' the base of natural logarithm in python

Tags: python, numpy, natural-logarithm

name 'e' is not defined
I ma getting this error in my python code.
I have already imported the math and the numpy modules. What more do I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
import math

math.e
```

Similar, for example:

```
import math

math.pi
```

This way, it is clear which `e` (or `pi`) or meant, instead of a random letter `e` somewhere in your code.

If you are using NumPy instead, you could do as follows:

```
import numpy as np

np.e
```

(the NumPy import is generally abbreviated to `np`).

Both `e`'s are the same.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
from math import e
```

You can now use 'e' in you code

or

```
import math
math.e
```

math.e will function as a float in your code

Comment: Don't tell people to use `import *`. It causes all kinds of name collision issues. For example, after `from math import *`, 3-argument `pow` stops working, because you've hidden the built-in `pow`.

Comment: Also, when you post an answer, don't just post code. Explain it.